# Javascript canvas - remove alpha from a loaded 4 bands RGB image to 3 bands JPEG image?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, png, draw

I have an image which is loaded from server and contains 4 bands in RGB format. Because of the alpha band which causes the image to look transparently, then I need to crop this alpha band and save it as JPEG format. One way I can think is using canvas, however, I'm not sure it possible or not as the test I did show that the image is the same.

```
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" src="data/with_alpha.png" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="2400" height="2097" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>


window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  var img = document.getElementById("scream");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  // This ones does not do anything to remove the alpha band
  c.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from http://sunbox.github.io/image-to-canvas-to-image/ it can be like this to convert canvas to image:

```
        // Get the image
        var sampleImage = document.getElementById("ringoImage"),
            canvas = convertImageToCanvas(sampleImage),
            image = convertCanvasToImage(canvas);  


        // Actions
        document.getElementById("pngHolder").appendChild(image);

        // Converts image to canvas; returns new canvas element
        function convertImageToCanvas(image) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);

            return canvas;
        }

        // Converts canvas to an image
        function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            return image;
        }
```